# Creating an 'order' model made up of 'products' and 'quantities' [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a specific question that is also quite general.

I want to create a database entity called 'order' which is made up of 'products' and quantities of the products. I think I have the first few steps done:

First I will create the order and product models

```
rails g model product
rails g model order
rails g migration createJoinTableProductOrder product order 
rails db:migrate
```

How can I seed the database with the following:

1. Orders that are associated to many products
2. Information about the quantity of each product in each order

The seeds should be something like this:

```
Product A 
Product B

Order 1 has 3 of Product A and 2 of Product B
Order 2 has 1 of Product A and 1 of Product B
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you want to seed needs more explanation.

Comment: added some pseudocode :)

Comment: There is no pseudocode in the question. That is more like an output you want.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how can I create the seeds as shown in the pseudocode :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain with example

```
class Product
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end

class Order
 has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Creating Order and products

```
order_1 = Order.create(:name => "Order1")
products_a = 3.each{|i| Product.create(name: "Product_A_#{i}")  }
products_b = 2.each{|i| Product.create(name: "Product_B_#{i}")  }
order_1.products << products_a
order_1.products << products_b
```

Now for order 2 repeat step

```
order_2 = Order.create(:name => "Order2")
product_a = Product.create(name: "Product_a")
product_b = Product.create(name: "Product_b") 
order_2.products << products_a
order_2.products << products_b
```

3rd table Products_orders will automatically be populated. Let me know if you need more explanation. just write same in seed to work. you can add further checks is products or user already exits etc.

Thanks

Comment: That makes so much sense, thank you! Just one more question, what is the best way for each order to know how many of each product it contains? I was thinking of using an object in a new column like: quantities: "{ #{product_A.id}: 12, #{product_B.id}: 4}"

Comment: @timothyylim you can use type category in Product table and then you can query like that 

@order.products.where(:product_type => 'A').count
@order.products.where(:product_type => 'B').count